# Python :In the last line it is showing syntax error.why?

Tags: python

```
def checkage(year,month,day):
today_day=11
today_month=6
today_year=2021
age=((today_year*365)+ 
(today_month*30)+today_day)- 
((year*365)+(month*30)+day)
print(age//12,"year",(age- 
((age//12)*365))//30,"month", 
(age-((age-
((age//12)*365))//30)*30,"days")
 
checkage(1996,12,11)
```

Python :In the last line it is showing syntax error.why?

Comment: take a look at [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), a [static linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) like it will help you pick out this type of error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more  `)` after `..."days")`

(that clears the syntax error, at least )

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly opening and closing brackets in your code. If you want a line of code to span across more lines, you need to make use of an additional bracket. You should also make use of indents to make your code more readable like so:

```
def checkage(year,month,day):
    today_day=11
    today_month=6
    today_year=2021
    age=(((today_year*365)+ 
         (today_month*30)+today_day)- 
         ((year*365)+(month*30)+day))
    print(age//12,
          "year",
          ((age-((age//12)*365))//30),
          "month", 
          (age-((age-((age//12)*365))//30)*30),"days")
 
checkage(1996,12,11)
```

output:

```
745 year -8766 month 271925 days
```

This doesnt seem to be doing the correct calculation either. If you want to work with dates you should consider the `datetime` library

```
from datetime import date
def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
print(calculate_age(date(1996, 12, 11)))
```

output:

```
24
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `)` in your last print statement.

```
def checkage(year,month,day):
   today_day=11
   today_month=6
   today_year=2021
   age=((today_year*365)+ (today_month*30)+today_day)- ((year*365)+(month*30)+day)
   print(age//12,"year",(age- ((age//12)*365))//30,"month", (age-((age-((age//12)*365))//30)*30,"days"))

checkage(1991,12,21)
```

Output

```
896 year -10543 month (327050, 'days')
```

P.S. Your logic isnt right, it takes even 51 as month which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the closing parenthesis of the `print` function;

```
def checkage(year,month,day):
    today_day=11
    today_month=6
    today_year=2021
    age=((today_year*365)+ 
    (today_month*30)+today_day)-((year*365)+(month*30)+day)
    print(age//12,"year",(age-((age//12)*365))//30,"month",(age-((age-((age//12)*365))//30)*30,"days"))
checkage(1996,12,11)
```